# powershell remote installing apps

Tags: powershell, installation

I am trying to install a msi from a network share remotely.

```
$app = [WMICLASS]"\\$pcname\ROOT\CIMV2:Win32_Product"
$app.Install($AppPath)
```

I am getting an err 1619. From some sources say that WMI cannot install remotely with first coping it to the local computer and running it. Some sources use this command to exactly.

That way works great, but I want to install via share so when the developer updates this msi, it will update the installed instances automagiclly. If I install them locally, the update would not be detected (not sure of this).

So I have tried using methods along these lines:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $pcname{ msiexec /quiet /i "\\appsvr\apps\theapp.msi" }
```

Those commands seem to go off into the blackhole, those that command works when run locally.

Anyone have a method for doing this that works?

Answer (score 3):

In your last scenario, you're credentials are likely getting lost.  This is known as the "double-hop authentication" (or maybe it's "second-hop") problem.  You're using creds from ServerA, to run something on ServerB, but it in the end has to connect to ServerC.

There's a fix if you have PowerShell v2 installed everywhere and are willing to accept the implications:
http://blogs.msdn.com/powershell/archive/2008/06/05/credssp-for-second-hop-remoting-part-i-domain-account.aspx